# What are the j2me bluetooth frameworks available?

Tags: frameworks, bluetooth, java-me

I am new to J2ME. I am working on a software which will send a image (taken from the camera) to a pc for further processing and am looking for a bluetooth framework. What are the ones, with good documentation and examples, available ?

Answer (score 1):

Bluetooth APIs for J2ME are defined [JSR 82: Java APIs for Bluetooth](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=82).

For usage information you can read for example:

- [Using the Java APIs for Bluetooth Wireless Technology, Part 1 - API Overview](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/apis/articles/bluetoothintro/index.html)
- [Using the Java APIs for Bluetooth, Part 2 - Putting the Core APIs to Work](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/apis/articles/bluetoothcore/)